# Get Coordinates of place\venue using google maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-geocoding-api

I'm using the autocomplete of Google maps to build navigation route,
I have an issue:
User can find a places like restaurants and etc, but I can't find the way to get there coordinates to my server side,
I've try to use

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={place name}
```

But I get Zero_Results
is there a way to retrieve the Coordinates of a place (not an address) using Maps api or Places api?

Comment: The response from the auto complete should contain the coordinates you need. [Places Detail Response](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details#PlaceDetailsRequests)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Geocoding API doesn't contain data for specific POI names, only the address information. If you get a Restaurant name of the Places Autocomplete API and you need the address or coordinates for it, the best option is to make a request to [Places Details API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details?hl=de) with this name. The response contains the address and the coordinates for a specific place.